# Ansible - remove user from group x if already in other group

Tags: list, dictionary, ansible, sudoers, json-query

I am looking for the easiest way to remove users from group x when they are already in group google-sudo. I store users in group vars in this kind of list and dictionary combination:

```
user_account:
  - name: jenny
    authorized_keys:
      - jenny_01
    groups:
      - "{% if not googlesudo.stat.exists %}sudo{% else %}google-sudo{% endif %}"

  - name: jerry
    authorized_keys:
      - jerry_01
    groups: 
      - "{% if not googlesudo.stat.exists %}sudo{% else %}google-sudo{% endif %}"
...
```

These are tasks I already created:

```
- name: Check if google-sudo file exists
  stat:
    path: /etc/sudoers.d/google_sudo
  register: googlesudo
  tags:
    - add_user_group
    - remove_from_x

- debug: var=googlesudo verbosity=2
  tags:
    - add_user_group
    - remove_from_x

- debug:
    msg: "User account to create: {{ item.name }}"
  with_items: "{{ user_account }}"

- name: "Creating user"
  user:
    name: "{{ item.name }}"
    group: users
    shell: /bin/bash
  with_items: "{{ user_account }}"

- name: Add user to additional groups
  user:
    name: "{{ item.0.name }}"
    groups: "{{ item.1 }}"
    append: yes
  with_subelements:
    - "{{ user_account }}"
    - groups
  tags:
    - remove_from_x

- name: Check if user already in google-sudo
  command: "groups {{ item.name }}"
  with_items:
    - "{{ user_account }}"
  register: root_users
  tags:
    - remove_from_x

- name: View root users
  debug:
    msg: "{{ item }}"
    verbosity: 2
  with_items:
    - "{{ root_users }}"
  tags:
    - remove_from_x

- name: Save state
  set_fact:
    is_in_googlesudo: "{{ root_users.results.0.stdout_lines }}"
  tags:
     - remove_from_x

- name: List
  debug: msg='{{ user_account |json_query("[?groups==`google-sudo`]")}}'
  tags:
    - remove_from_x

- name: Remove from x group
  shell: "deluser {{ item.name }} x"
  with_items:
    - "{{ user_account }}"
  when: "'x in is_in_googlesudo' and 'google-sudo in is_in_googlesudo'"
  tags:
    - remove_from_x
```

I was testing `json_query` to extract user name if he is in `google-sudo` and `x` group, but without success. Tried to list users when group is defined, however I get empty output, using this:

```
msg='{{ user_account |json_query("[?groups==`google-sudo`]")}}'
```

I wonder if is there any shorter way to remove users from group `x` after checking on server (using eg. `groups` command) or in `user_account` -> `group` if he's already in google-sudo.

Probably there is some nice and elegant way to write this code, I will appreciate any ideas how to deal with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's simplify the data, e.g.

```yaml
  vars:
    my_group: "{{ googlesudo.stat.exists|ternary('google-sudo', 'sudo') }}"
    user_account:
      - name: jenny
        groups: "{{ my_group }}"
      - name: jerry
        groups: "{{ my_group }}"
```

The code works as expected, e.g.

```yaml
    - stat:
        path: /tmp/google_sudo
      register: googlesudo
    - debug:
        var: user_account
    - debug:
        msg: '{{ user_account|json_query("[?groups==`google-sudo`].name") }}'
```

gives if /tmp/google_sudo exists

```yaml
  user_account:
  - groups: google-sudo
    name: jenny
  - groups: google-sudo
    name: jerry

  msg:
  - jenny
  - jerry
```

otherwise

```yaml
  user_account:
  - groups: sudo
    name: jenny
  - groups: sudo
    name: jerry

  msg: []
```

---

Q: *"**Remove user from group x if already in another group.**"*

A: Use [getent](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/getent_module.html#ansible-builtin-getent-a-wrapper-to-the-unix-getent-utility) to get the list of users in a group. For example, to list users in the group *sudo*

```yaml
    - getent:
        database: group
    - debug:
        var: getent_group.sudo.2
```

Test action if a user is a member of the group *sudo*, e.g.

```yaml
    - debug:
        msg: "Remove user {{ item.name }} from group x"
      loop: "{{ user_account }}"
      when: item.name in getent_group.sudo.2
```

---

Q: *"**Have groups as a list. (Probably I should use contains function.)**"*

A: Yes. Use [contains](https://jmespath.readthedocs.io/en/latest/specification.html#contains), e.g given the lists

```yaml
  vars:
    user_account:
      - name: jenny
        groups: [google-sudo, group2]
      - name: jerry
        groups: [google-sudo, group3]
```

the task

```yaml
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ user_account|json_query('[?contains(groups, `group2`)].name') }}"
```

gives

```yaml
  msg:
  - jenny
```

Comment: Yes, it works! Thanks Vladimir, you rescue me once again. :)

Comment: One more thing. I need to have groups as a list specified for every user, not in form of dictionary. How then json_query should look like -> `{{ user_account|json_query("[?groups==`google-sudo`].name") }}' Actually, the question is if I can use json_query for this combination or should use other solution.

Comment: Probably I should use `contains` function.

Comment: Ok, I already figure it out. This works with groups in list -> '{{ user_account|json_query("[?groups[0]==`google-sudo`].name") }}'

Comment: I've updated the answer. Open new questions if you have more issues.